# Calculate SHA1 fingerprint of (unsigned char *) in python

Tags: python, sha

I am working on a project related to Data deduplication. I need to design a fingerprint calculation module (to calculate the fingerprint of file chunk) which will take two inputs and give an output.

Input : `some_module(unsigned char*buffer, uint32 buffer_length)`

output: `unsigned char* fingerprint`

I have been asked to design a class to implement above the module. I will use `hashlib` but my question is How do I select proper data-types to do this in Python ?

Comment: Python doesnt do static type checking. So don't worry about it, but about DEA :p

Comment: @thefourtheye why do you have to worry about the [**DEA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_Enforcement_Administration) here?

Comment: @KDawG Breaking Bad's protagonist's name is Heisenberg.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I select proper data-types to do this in Python ?

You could use Python strings (`str`) for both the input and the output.

If you do, you'll be able to use `hashlib.sha1()` directly, without needing any datatype conversions.

Comment: Well that cleared my doubt. I have another question. Does the length of buffer matter while calculating fingerprint?

Comment: It does, but `str` will keep track of its length.